# Propagate Sleuth baggage on parallel streams

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-cloud-sleuth

This question is exactly the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616780/sleuth-traceid-and-spanid-are-not-propagated-to-parallelstream-worker-threads), which wasn't actually answered (that code only uses one thread). My code looks like this at the moment

```
CompletableFuture completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            foo.stream().parallel()
                    .forEach(bar -> {
                                //business logic
                            }
                    );
            return null;
        }, new TraceableExecutorService(this.beanFactory, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads), "fooBarStream"));

completableFuture.get();
```

yet only one thread is correctly traced. Using `.parallelStream()` or a `LazyTraceExecutor` directly instead of a `TraceableExecutorService` didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work thanks to [this example](https://github.com/vaquarkhan/spring-cloud-sleuth-examples/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/executor/TraceableExecutorServiceTests.java). The snippet above becomes:

```
TraceableExecutorService executorService = new TraceableExecutorService(this.beanFactory, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads), "fooStream");
CompletableFuture.allOf(runnablesBusinessLogic(foo,executorService)).get();
```

where `runnablesBusinessLogic` is

```
private CompletableFuture<Void>[] runnablesBusinessLogic(List<FooBar> foo, ExecutorService executorService) {
    List<CompletableFuture<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (FooBar f : foo) {
        futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            businessLogic(f);
            return;
        }, executorService));
    }
    return futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]);
}
```

If I understood the example (and the [discussion](https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/archives/2018/06/18) behind the current status of the documentation) correctly, Sleuth cannot work with a `ForkJoinPool` (and so with parallel streams) automatically. The main idea to make it work is not to create a `CompletableFuture` and split it, but to create several futures (and join them).